# Backup without the help of softwares

Tags: backup, vps, centos6

I am quite new to VPS, although I have become comfortable setting up Nginx, PHP-FPM, MySql, git and other tools in CentOs, plus do some basic security and *A Lot!* optimization drills, all through shell access. I am now stuck at the most important part; How to do a proper backup.

Here is the what I know so far, that regular backup is good, and should be done at-least once a month using a software of your choice. I agree with the most part and I am prepared to do a backup, but I feel comfortable just using something like this.

```
$ tar -cvzf www-backup-july-2014.tar.gz var/www
```

Now, All I would need to do is send the archived file to some site of mine like this:

```
$ mv www-backup-july-2014.tar.gz /var/www/public/mysite.com/
```

and just download the tar file, and remove it from the the public folder afterwards.

Now given that script, it seems like I am missing what the all the talk in the word of safeguarding your data (backup-wise), because that works, albeit with small limitation.

Now as you might have guessed my only question is obviously:

1: What is wrong with the above method? and..

Comment: So does your website interact with a database at all?  If so, then a simple tar command is completely missing all the data from your database.  If you want to figure out how to do a backup, the best way to do it is to try using your backups to build a new working server in a VM somewhere.  If you can't build a working system from your backups, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Zoredache Yes. Almost all my sites make use of the mysql database. The above was just an example. I am backing up, `var/lib/mysql` too. And `var/etc/nginx/conf.f/` Those are what I usually backup (just incase I need to re-install my VPS)

Comment: Your question is nonsensical.  All operations on a computer use "softwares".  Tar is software.  Gzip is software.  All of linux is a collection of software.  Without software your computer is primarily useful as a paperweight.

Comment: If you are using tar to backup mysql, you are doing it **wrong**.  The files have a very high chance of being corrupt.

Comment: @Zoredache What should I use then? I tought taring this way `tar -cvzf` was the most recommended style, as it preserves file permission/selinux options.

Comment: tar is perfectly fine, so long as none of the files are locked, or open for writing.  A quick search on this site or Google for 'mysql backup', would have sent you to the aptly named 'mysqlbackup' command.

Comment: @Zoredache I actually use mysqldump command. Because taring /var/lib/mysql/ gave me some problems. Do you know a small bash script that can backup specific dir? I takes me 5 minutes to go to each dir, and do it manually because I 0 shell skills :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say a good backup happens much more often than once a month - but if you are ok with losing the last month of work on your server, that's up to you.

Software that was actually designed to do backups have a lot of things going for them though.  Off the top of my head:

- Automated.  No chance of you forgetting to run them.
- Email notifications if they fail.  Or if they succeed.
- Well tested.  Are you sure you can catch every case where your backups seem to work but don't actually?  Most backup software will catch all the common ways it can fail (though nothing is perfect, so you still need to test your backups!)
- Properly backs up databases.
- Has documented restore procedures.
- Keeps X previous backups, in case the latest is corrupt or you don't notice something needs restoring right away.
- Possibly transfers new backups as diffs through rsync or similar so you don't need to transfer all the data every time, just what has changed.
- Properly handle permissions, ownership, UID/GID mapping, device files, temporary files, etc.

Sure, you can most of that manually.  But it is error prone and requires reinventing wheels that already exist.  There are plenty of free suitable backup tools that can backup your website and databases, or the whole server.  With your backup plan you miss everything that isn't in /var/www - databases, and configuration files for your web and database servers being the most important.  Backing up the entire server (except things like /tmp, /proc, and /dev) is generally a good idea, even if you never plan on restoring all the data you don't risk missing something important.

Comment: Do you have any utilities, that you can suggest as alternative to just doing `tar -cvzf ...` ?

Comment: I find backupninja (https://labs.riseup.net/code/projects/backupninja) to work quite well.